# Laravel multiple database queues not working

Tags: laravel

In my **.env** file:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

In **config/queue.php**

```
'connections' => [
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
    'arbitrage' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'arbitrage',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
     'notifications' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'notifications',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
],
```

Then when I run `ProcessArbitrage::dispatch();` it works. If I run `ProcessArbitrage::dispatch()->onQueue('arbitrage');` it doesn't process.

I'm running locally and `php artisan queue:listen` is active. I've tried `cache:clear` and `config:clear` as well, but no luck. When I simply remove `onQueue('arbitrage')` the job process, if I add it doesn't so there's something wrong with the queue setup I guess but can not seem to find it. No error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Asked 1 minute ago... I needed to run `php artisan queue:listen --queue=arbitrage,notifications`. I though that was only needed if you wanted to prioritize the queues, it was unclear to me from the docs that this is what you need to run in order for it to process custom queues.